# How to use baud rate 4mb with FTDI on OSX?

Tags: macos, ftdi, baud-rate

Is it possible to use a baud rate of 4mb (B4000000) with Apple's FTDI driver?  Or is FTDI's VCP driver better?

Speeds up to B230400 are defined in termios.h (*), with each speed being defined as the integer matching its speed (unlike Linux).  However, the simple hack `#define B4000000 4000000` does not work.

I remember being able to use 4mb with FTDI around 5 years ago (before Apple provided a driver) using FTDI's VCP driver and hacking `FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/Info.plist` to make one of the "allowed" speeds (like B2400) be aliased to 4mb by the driver.  Is this still the recommended method?  (I suppose this would require disabling kext security, with `sudo nvram kext-dev-mode=1`.)

I am using the baud rate like this, where `serBaudRate` is something like `B2400` or (ideally) `B4000000`.

```
if ((fd = open(serPortName, O_RDWR)) < 0)   { perror("aborting"); return; }
tcgetattr(fd, &tty);                            /* get attributes */
cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t) serBaudRate);       /* output speed */
cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t) serBaudRate);       /* input speed */
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty);                   /* set attributes */
```

(*) the full path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/termios.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I remember being able to use 4mb with FTDI around 5 years ago (before
>   Apple provided a driver) using FTDI's VCP driver and hacking
>   FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/Info.plist to make one of the
>   "allowed" speeds (like B2400) be aliased to 4mb by the driver. Is this
>   still the recommended method? (I suppose this would require disabling
>   kext security, with sudo nvram kext-dev-mode=1.)

I suspect this is the only way to do it. The Apple driver is pretty basic (as of a few years ago it didn't even support CTS/RTS signals) and I don't see any way to specify a non-standard baud rate. Looks like the FTDI `Info.plist` still supports those baud rate config options too.

Comment: could you refer to this Info.plist method?